# Mask area of GeoTIFFs surrounded by 0 Data

Tags: gdal, grass-gis, rasterio, digital-image-processing

I've a larger amount of GeoTIFFs which basically look like:

[image]

The area of interest is the rectangle in the middle.
Black shows 0-Data.

My goal is to fill the left and right sided areas (round) with 0-data as well.

[image]

My idea is to only "look" at a half of the image which then would describe the area to be filled with 0-data as `if surrounded by 0-data fill with 0-data`. (The rectangle then should be ignored as it's not surrounded by 0-data on the right hand side).

[image]

So much for theory. If this sounds doable my question is if somebody knows of a tool with CLI support which already provides this kind of calculation/workflow?

Comment: If the rectangle is at about the same place in each image why not to draw a area of interest around that and discard everything outside the AOI?

Comment: It's position is varying.

Comment: If you have many of these, and the area of interest and/or the area to-be-filtered have somewhat consistent properties across your images, I would recommend you use something like regionprops to detect the "blobs" in  your image, compute some of their morphological properties (in your shown case, major_axis_length would work), then filter them and save the filtered image as a geotiff by copying the CRS info from the original geotiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very difficult to do that with python gdal module. You only need two X references for avoiding rounded shapes. First, I downloaded your image and arbitrarily assigned a CRS to it. It looks like (for one band) as follows:

[image]

Afterward, I put two reference points (in blue) as in following image.

[image]

I write down its respective X coordinates (first_Xref = 438955.30914411816,     second_Xref = 439411.52302646986) for using in following code:

```
import gdal, osr

rasterfn = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster.tif'
newRasterfn = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster_new.tif'

raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)

geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
originX = geotransform[0]
originY = geotransform[3]
pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]

band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadAsArray()

cols = array.shape[1]
rows = array.shape[0]

first_Xref = 438955.30914411816
second_Xref = 439411.52302646986

x = originX
y = originY

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if ( x < first_Xref and array[i][j] != 0 ) or ( x > second_Xref and array[i][j] != 0 ):
            array[i][j] = 0
        x += pixelWidth
    x = originX
    y += pixelHeight

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(array)
outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
outRaster = None
```

After running it in Python Console, produced raster looks as expected:

[image]